# HTML Date Format

Tags: javascript, date

In HTMl How can I change the format of date? Using date() I got today's date.The problem is I don't know how to change the format of the date. I have to display the date format like this "May 28th 2013". Can any one help me ???

```
    <html position="0,0,0,0" canExport="false">
    <![CDATA[
        <script>
            var currentTime = new Date();
            var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
            var monthname ;
            if (month == 1)
                monthname = "Jan";
            else if (month == 2)
                monthname = "Feb";
            else if (month == 3)
                monthname = "Mar";
            else if (month == 4)
                monthname = "Apr";
            else if (month == 5)
                monthname = "May";
            else if (month == 5)
                monthname = "June";
            else if (month == 7)
                monthname = "July";
            else if (month == 8)
                monthname = "Aug";
            else if (month == 9)
                monthname = "Sep";
            else if (month == 10)
                monthname = "Oct";
            else if (month == 11)
                monthname = "Nov";
            else 
                monthname = "Dec";

            var day = currentTime.getDate();
            var dayname;
            if (day == 2 ||day == 22 )
                dayname = "nd";
            else if (day == 3 ||day == 23 )
                dayname = "rd";
            else if (day == 1 ||day == 21||day == 31 )
                dayname = "st";
            else 
                dayname = "th";

            var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
            s = currentTime.toDateString();
            alert(s);
            $('[name=DateDynamic]').text(monthname+" "+day+""+dayname+" "+ year);

        </script>
    ]]>
</html>
```

Currently I am following the above big method.I know there should be some simple method.

Comment: Style of this questions suggests that it must be about PHP…

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Comment: Use this [JS API](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)

Comment: @NullPointerException an API just for date formatting? **WHY?**

Comment: There is a "Date()" in javascript; what's with all the PHP responses?

Comment: I am not sure what is going on here. Why did you change [javascript] to [php], @JohnConde?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want this for javascript? Don't you? Assuming your tags

Try something like:

Javascript code:

```
var currentDate = new Date()
var day = currentDate.getDate()
var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
month = getMonthName(month);
var year = currentDate.getFullYear()
document.write("<b>" +month + " " + day  + " " + year + "</b>")

function getMonthName(monthNumber)
{
    var monthName = "";
     switch (monthNumber)
     {
         case 5:
         monthName = "May";
             break;
         default:
             monthName ="not implemented yet";
             break;
     }
    return monthName;
}
```

Edit--->
I see you have changed your tags. I lieve it up here for anyone!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using different languages, but I'm guessing you want to use the Date object in Javascript if you're wanting to display a simple date when the page loads.

Here's a tutorial on the many ways to format dates using Javascript:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think the Javascript method `toDateString` might be want you are looking for:

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString)

```
 var now = new Date();
 x = now.toDateString();
 //Fri May 31 2013

 //Additional Formatting
 var patt = /(\w+) (\w+ [0-9]{1,2}) ([0-9]{4})/;
 x = x.replace(patt, '$2, $3');
 //May 31, 2013
```

I put together a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tuxgb/) to handle your 'day suffix' issue.

Output of Fiddle:

```
 //May 31st, 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myDate = new Date();

var formattedDate = myDate.toDateString().split(' ')
formattedDate[0] = '';


if (formattedDate[2][0] != 1 && formattedDate[2][1] == 1) {
    formattedDate[2] = formattedDate[2] + 'st';
} else if (formattedDate[2][0] != 1 && formattedDate[2][1] == 2) {
    formattedDate[2] = formattedDate[2] + 'nd';    
} else if (formattedDate[2][0] != 1 && formattedDate[2][1] == 3) {
    formattedDate[2] = formattedDate[2] + 'rd';
} else {
    formattedDate[2] = formattedDate[2] + 'th';
}

formattedDate = formattedDate.join(' ');
```

Output for today: May 31st 2013
http://jsfiddle.net/VHqpU/2/

Comment: This solution does not account for dates in the 'teen' range. See my solution.

Comment: @ExceptionLimeCat You are absolutely right; I've updated my solution to address that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, I cleaned it up a bit. You were also using `getDate()` for you "day" variable instead of `getDay()`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var currentTime = new Date();

        var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
        var months = ["Dec","Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","June","July","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov",];
        var monthname = months[month];

        var day = currentTime.getDay();
        var dayname;
        if (day == 2 ||day == 22 )
            dayname = "nd";
        else if (day == 3 ||day == 23 )
            dayname = "rd";
        else if (day == 1 ||day == 21||day == 31 )
            dayname = "st";
        else 
            dayname = "th";

        var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
        alert(monthname+" "+day+""+dayname+" "+ year);
        $('[name=DateDynamic]').text(monthname+", "+day+""+dayname+" "+ year);

    </script>
```